# How to open ports on Windows Server 2003 RTM from the command prompt

Tags: windows-server-2003, firewall, command-line-interface, port

I want to open the port number 1433 in Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition (5.2, Build 3790) without any Service Pack with out having Firewall, exists a way for achieve this via prompt?

**EDIT: I dont have Service Pack 1, so I cant use the firewall option in netsh..**

thanks!

Comment: Please install the service pack, it makes me nervous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the RTM build you're probably using the Internet Connection Firewall (ICF). [KB317530](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317530) describes how to open a port if you are using ICF (see step 6).

**Edit:** I just saw you want to do this via the command line. AFAIK there is no built-in command line interface for ICF. However you could use the [Internet Connection Firewall Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E3B0DD6A-7537-4E84-AF8C-B7A89DB4E628&displaylang=en) for this. (It's for Windows XP Embedded but it should work on Windows Server 2003.) This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838519%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx) describes how to use the tool.

Comment: the utility attemps to restart server?, I mean is necesary to restart the SO, cause that servers is running on production enviroment. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused as to what your asking, but if your trying to open a port in Windows firewall using the command prompt rather than GUI you can do so with netsh

```
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 1433 NameOfService enable
```

Answer (score 2):

To open a port 1433 on the Windows Firewall

```
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 1433 ExceptionName enable subnet
```